# Can Antlr detect missing lexer tokens

Tags: antlr

I'm using the Java syntax defined at https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java/java

My user somehow input his Java code as the following

```java
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         * my first program !
         */
        System.out.println("Hello, World!"); 
    }
}
```

He just forgets /* before line 3, but my parser is screwed up.

```cs
var stream = CharStreams.fromString(input);
ITokenSource lexer = new JavaLexer(stream);

ITokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
Parser parser = new JavaParser(tokens);

var tree = parser.compilationUnit();
```

The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference claims Antlr can do single token insertion and single token deletion but I didn't find it's inserting `/*` for me.

How would I ask Antlr to recover from the missing `/*`?

Comment: The problem here is that '/*' is not a token. This is a lexical error, not parser error. The lexer works independently of parser, without context. It just returns `*`, `my`, `first`, ..., `*`, `/`.

Comment: At the point of a parse error, you'd need to scan forward to confirm `*` and `/` contiguously, then rewind/rewrite the token and char streams and reset the parser afterward. I don't know if it's possible, but I wouldn't be surprised if one can.

Comment: @kaby76 Is there a way to insert something to CharStreams?